# How to map hierarchical Json to ItemFileWriteStore?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have Json data that has children elements. I need to bind the store to an editable grid and have the edits populated to the store.
The data tree does get populated into the ItemFileWriteStore. The datagrid displays only the parent data and none of the children data.

SAMPLE.TXT

```
    {
    "items": [
        {
            "profileId": "1",
            "profileName": "ABC",
            "profileType": "EmailProfile",
            "profilePreferences": [
                {
                    "profilePreferenceId": "1",
                    "displayText": "Bob",
                    "address": "primary@some.com"
                },
                {
                    "profilePreferenceId": "2",
                    "displayText": "Sally",
                    "address": "secondary@some.com"
                },
                {
                    "profilePreferenceId": "3",
                    "displayText": "Joe",
                    "address": "alternate@some.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

javascript

```
var sampleLayout = [
  [
  { field: 'profileName', name: 'profileName', width: '100px' },
  { field: 'profilePreferences.displayText', name: 'displayText', width: '100px' },
  { field: 'profilePreferences.address', name: 'address', width: '100px' }      
  ]];


function populateGrid() {
    var url = "sample.txt"; //Will be replaced with endpoint URL

    dojo.xhrGet({
        handleAs: 'json',
        url: url,
        error: function (e) {
            alert("Error: " + e.message);
        },
        load: showJsonData
    });
}


function showJsonData(response, ioArgs) {
    var profileStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        data: {
            items: response.items
        }
    });

    var sampleGrid = dijit.byId("sampleGrid");
    sampleGrid.store = profileStore;
    sampleGrid.startup();
}
```

Comment: What should the display look like? (e.g., nested rows, flattened with a different class name.)

Comment: The display should be flattened to a grid with three columns (profileName, displayText, address). The grid would have three rows; one for each of the profilePreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to be using **dojox.grid.TreeGrid** or 'fake' the JSON to present every even row with a blank profileName. Two samples follows, one for TreeGrid another on DataGrid - not tested in working environment though.

Given **Hierachial JSON**:

```
{
  identifier: 'id' // a good custom to make an id pr item, note spaces and odd chars are invalid

      items: [{
         id: '1',
         profileName: 'Admin',
         profilePreferences: [
           { id: '1_1', displayText: 'John Doe', address: 'Big Apple' }
           { id: '1_2', displayText: 'Jane Doe', address: 'Hollywood' }
         ]

      }, {
         id: '2',
         profileName: 'Visitor',
         profilePreferences: [
           { id: '2_1', displayText: 'Foo', address: 'Texas' }
           { id: '2_2', displayText: 'Bar', address: 'Indiana' }
         ]

      }]
    }
```

**TreeGrid Structure**:

```
{
    cells: [
      [
        { field: "profileName", name: "profileName", width: "100px" },
        { field: "profilePreferences",
          children: [
            { field: "displayText" name: "displayText", width: "100px" },
            { field: "address" name: "address", width: "100px" }
          ]
      ]
    ]
  }
```

reference: [dojo docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/grid/TreeGrid.html)

Given **flattened 'fake-children' JSON**:

```
{
  identifier: 'id' // a good custom to make an id pr item, note spaces and odd chars are invalid

      items: [{
         id: '1',
         profileName: 'Admin', preferenceText: '', preferenceAddr: ''
     }, {
        id: '2', 
        profileName: '',      preferenceText: 'John', preferenceAddr: 'NY'
     }, {
         id: '3',
         profileName: 'Visitor', preferenceText: '', preferenceAddr: ''
     }, {

         id: '4',         // Not with '.' dot seperator like so
         profileName: '',    preference.Text: 'Jane Doe', preference.Addr: 'Hollywood'
     } ]
```

**DataGrid structure**:

```
[[
  {'name': 'Profilename', 'field': 'profileName', 'width': '100px'},
  {'name': 'User name', 'field': 'preferenceText', 'width': '100px'},
  {'name': 'Address', 'field': 'preferenceAddr', 'width': '200px'}
]]
```

reference [dojo docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html)

Comment: I'll be presentened as a flattened view. Also, there is limited flexibility in the json structure that I receive.

Comment: I'm curious, do child elements always need to be named "childred" in order to be compatible with TreeGrid? If so, how would it handle multiple differently-named child nodes?

Comment: that depends on the model.. if you do not control the json, look into ForestStoreModel config (ctor) parameter 'childrenAttrs'. However, the standard grid is model-less and operates directly on the attached store, so

Comment: you problem is the 'preferences.displayText' key, to process it correctly it must be { field: 'preferences', children: [ { field:'displayText' .. }] }. However, you want to achieve a flat grid, in that case 'children' is not an option ill put two examples in

Comment: In your Hierachial JSON, must both the parent's and children's identifier have the same name. e.g. 'id'? My data has distinct id names: profileId and profilePreferenceId

Comment: yes or else the store wont construct, believe you will have an exception there, stores operate on ID's alone really, then the children mappings are simply references. See http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dojo/trunk/tests/data/countries_references.json, notice how every children object refers to the 'identifier' value

Comment: This one is hierachial without references - as example above, the easiest concept to grasp imho: http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dojo/trunk/tests/data/geography_hierarchy_large.json

Comment: RE: both the parent's and children's identifier must have the same name. That's something I didn't know. Thx!